Would it be possible to preview the title like it is the case with the text body?
Would it be possible to preview the title like it is the case with the text body?
Might not it help?
I've been forced many times to edit the title to make it clear, mostly in a typographical way.
I am often blocked by the number of characters limit.
My questions are not clear or argued enough some of the same times.
If it helps one person, maybe it could it help everyone, one day.

This makes perfect sense on sites with MathJax enabled. On those sites, equation markup in titles is rendered, and seeing what an equation looks like before publication is important.

@SonictheAnonymousHedgehog was elected as the man of the situation by me, for my situation, because I just looked at it right now. Thank you man. Let's have a look at others thoughts now.

Are you asking specifically about MathJax? Because I was not aware that some types of title formatting are available on some sites. If so, please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly mention your use case.

No, if I might, I let the deciders/developers decide where it could mostly help, or if eventually, it could help "everywhere". I am not at all an expert of the necessary knowledges to answer your question. I am mostly on scientific stackexchanges.

In that case, I'd caution that this request may be met with disagreement from people who don't participate in sites with MathJax and not aware of its being rendered in titles (e.g. because questions with MathJax in titles are excluded from Hot Network Questions) who don't see why it should be done. You've already got two disagreeing answers to this question. Adding in the case of MathJax in titles is your best shot of actually getting this feature change done.

or I try to be patient and let "time" decide if my question was wise enough. But I note your point, without being able to know if it serves the most, which is also, my goal. I may just end in a categorical failure, but I am not presently in the mood of argumentation. I slept 2 hours in 20... and still have to work. Thanks still again.

A few related posts: Can we get a preview for titles when writing questions?,
Please include the title in the question preview and
Show a preview of the title when editing/asking - at least on the MathJax sites.

As a workaround, you can write the body first and then copy out whatever equation you might need for the title. (The downside here is that it may be over the character limit.)

And sometimes, the solution appears, without any more necessary developper work. @Laurel, write about simplicity one day?

The removal of the obfuscated profanity is appropriate here. Please do not roll that change back. If you wish to reword the section where it says "My questions are not clear or argued enough some of the same times.", you are welcome to do so.

@someone there are more than enough sites where profanity is common and welcome. Not here.

I was only talking about the last moderation edit. I just put the most simple answer to the question to me, in the body of the question, maybe pretending... but wishing simplification, and efficacy, and respecting what the precedent moderator asked saying something like "Please, keep it as suggested". Maybe, would I get unhappily more credit to you, saying I am handicapped... Anyway, I "have" my answer...

I find it rather hard to understand your writing style, so maybe I've misunderstood what you're trying to say. On Stack Exchange sites, we do not edit answers into the question body.

@someone I didn't see your most recent comment/edit, but yeah, what PM 2Ring said is why your most recent change was rolled back: Answers in the question body are generally rolled back and codified into answers. You can provide your own answer below if you think it's worth providing for the future. I apologize for the friction here. It's not readily apparent that this is the way we do things.

conventions... ok  ok


I've been forced many times to edit the title to make it clear.

Body previews aren't intended to help you "make your question clear." If content quality was the main concern, we wouldn't need a preview at all - you could get the exact same information just by looking at the plain text. It's all there in the text; you can judge whether it's clear or not just by reading it.
Instead, the reason body previews are useful is markdown formatting. It can be hard to guess what your question will look like just from the plain text, especially if you have minor errors like confusing *italics* and **bold** or thinking that strikethrough uses ~~double tildes~~ instead of <s>tags</s>. Previews help you spot mistakes like that beforehand to make sure your question will look the way you want it to.
Titles don't support markdown - what you see is what you get. Therefore, you don't need to watch out for markdown errors. If you want to know if your title needs editing, you can read it straight from the textbox - no preview needed.

Maths require specific typos, that might need to be clearer in title preview.

The title is always plain text. Its clarity depends on its own merits - there's no layout/markup(down) issues to worry about. Previews are useful when you're not confident your markdown is correct so seeing what the person reading the finalised post is useful. In the case of your title, what you see is what everyone else sees.
In this case the textbox feels like an acceptable way to preview it.

On a narrow screen, only a few words in the title box are visible. That's why the preview (shown while editing with 2k on many sites) is helpful.

ah, I guess that's a blind spot. I'm >2k on most sites I am active in

Note that your statement that "The title is always plain text." is not necessarily true where MathJax is used (i.e., with any sites which support that, such as Mathematics SE). In those cases, some sort of preview could be helpful. Nonetheless, the MathJax being used there should rarely be particularly complicated so, even in those cases, a preview would be of limited value.

This makes perfect sense on sites with MathJax enabled. On those sites, equation markup in titles is rendered, and seeing what an equation looks like before publication is important.
